# What is the difference between "in" and "for" in "hasn't eaten in five months"?

Tags: prepositions, present-perfect

> Now the cubs are growing, fed on mom's milk, but mom herself hasn't eaten **in** five months, and is getting thinner by the day.

What does *in* mean here, and how would the meaning of that piece change if *for* were used?

Comment: Interesting question! Judging by **[this](https://books.google.ru/books?id=1C6-AwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA40&ots=XRlXmYZCl1&dq=%22hasn't%20eaten%20in%22%20%20preposition%20%22in%22&hl=ru&pg=PA40#v=onepage&q=%22hasn't%20eaten%20in%22%20%20preposition%20%22in%22&f=false)**, it could be an American English / British English thing. Other searchable combinations include `"hasn't had * in"` vs `"hasn't had * for"`.

Comment: this better goes as an answer @CopperKettle

Comment: @MaulikV - no, I'm not sure; the author of the book is clearly not a native speaker

Comment: I think *"...hasn't eaten **for**"* is more common as compared to *'in'*. I'd certainly prefer 'for'. @CopperKettle However, I find both 'for' and 'in' in BrE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found two similar questions in the English Language & Usage section: [[1]](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48950/can-the-preposition-in-be-used-instead-of-for-in-the-following-sentence), [[2]](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/239995/use-of-prepositions-in-and-for-with-present-perfect-tense).

It seems that ***in*** and ***for*** may be used interchangeably in negative sentences, although in positive sentences only ***for*** is correct. The use of ***in*** in such cases is more common in American English.

Comment: Right. And the reason is that _in weeks_ is a ***[Negative Polarity Item (NPI)](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf)***, while _for weeks_ isn't. This means that using _in weeks/months/years/ages_ is ungrammatical unless there's some negative around creating a negative context. But _for weeks_ is fine anywhere. E.g, **He has been here in weeks* is ungrammatical -- and unclear, both because the sentence contains no negative; but *He has been here for weeks* is grammatical and clear because it doesn't need a negative.

Answer (score -1):

In is used in this context to describe the duration of what ever it is you are measuring.  Using the word for in this context will not change it's meaning