# 'In a very long time' vs 'for a very long time'

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-structure

I was watching friends lately and on that show Ross said "I haven't had sex in a very long time". I wonder why he didn't said "I haven't had sex for a very long time" although 'in a very long time' sounds more native and correct but why not he used  'for a very long time '.

So, this is my question when do we use *'in a very long time'* and when do we use *'for a very long time'*.

Comment: Related: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/68352/what-is-the-difference-between-in-and-for-in-hasnt-eaten-in-five-months

Answer (score 0):

The phrase *"for a very long time"* is ambiguous and can have two meanings depending on how it is used. It can mean the distance between events in time or the duration of an event in time. This double entendre can often be a useful element of humour for the comedy writer; but in this case they wanted to avoid the laughs and stick to the single meaning. Thus using *"in a very long time"* which only communicates the distance between events in time.

I am sure you can now make some very funny jokes using the *"for a very long time"* variant, particular when *long time* itself can refer to distance measurements; but that might be another direction of humour entirely. I'll leave that to your imagination.